# Checking to see entry of custom class is in List Array using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ive done alot of searching on the net and on here(foundLOTS of useful entries that helped me out)
In need of help trying to figure something out.
Im currently developing a game for my son.  And I am creating a inventory system.  Im using a List to hold all of the current items in his inventory but its reference to a custom class.

HERE is the class so far for setting up the items.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Item  
{
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
    public int ID;
    public int Type;
    public int Quantity;
    // Use this for initialization
    public Item(string newName, string newDesc, int newId, int newType, int newQty)
    {
        Name = newName;
        Description = newDesc;
        ID = newId;
        Type = newType;
        Quantity = newQty;
    }
}
```

in my playerstats i have a few items entered just to test things

```
void SetStartingInventory()
{
    Inventory.Add( new Item("Rookie Ball","Stater Capturing Device",1,1,5));
    Inventory.Add( new Item("Potion", "Replenish 5 health points.",2,2,2));
}
```

everything will display properly and i know i dont have a proper database setup yet for items this is more along the lines to test things out and find something that works..
im sure there is a better and more organized way to keep this.

ANYWAYS!  for testing purposes i want to press the g button  which is a no brainer i got that.
what i want to do is find if there is already an entry in the Inventory list, that matches say.. "Potion" or its item ID#, if returns true, what is the index of that entry so i could give another potion and incease my quantity by one.

any help and guidance be massively helpful.

Comment: are you familiar with the `string.Contains()` method.. also have you considered using a `List<T> or creating a small class of Item of it's own like CustItem using auto properties` there are HasTables, Dictionary's HashSets, etc... too many different ways to skin this cat..

Comment: also you could have `SetStartingInventory(string name)` accept a string name param as well

Comment: no i havent,  i am realativly new to c# and finding my way pretty decently.. i think at least. just run into a few snags here and there.  ill definitly take a look into  the different approaches you have suggested thankyou !  I have been able to get it to work so far using for() so far but im sure it will get too difficult as i start adding more items into play.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a quick look to extension methods provided by [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to Enumerable collections. It let you query enumerable collections in very simple ways.

For example here's a quick example looking for a potion with an id greater than 20.

```
using System.Linq;
List<Item> items;

Item[] potionItemWithIdsGreaterThan20 = 
  items.Where(i => i.Name.Equals("Potion") && i.ID > 20).ToArray();
```